# Count frequency of words inside a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, nested-lists

I have a list of common keywords:

```
common_keywords = ['dog', 'person', 'cat']
```

And a list of dictionaries, containing keywords and sometimes the `common_keywords` listed above:

```
people = [{'name':'Bob', 'keywords': ['dog', 'dog', 'car', 'trampoline']},
          {'name':'Kate', 'keywords': ['cat', 'jog', 'tree', 'flower']},
           {'name':'Sasha', 'keywords': ['cooking', 'stove', 'person', 'cat']}]
```

I would like to count the frequency of the `common_keywords` for each person, so the desired output would look something like:

```
counts = [{'name': 'Bob', 'counts': [{'dog': 2}]}, 
          {'name': 'Kate', 'counts': [{'cat': 1}]}, 
          {'name': 'Sasha', 'counts': [{'person':1}, {'cat': 1}]]
```

I am able to use `dict(Counter())` to count the keywords and filter them if they appear in the `common_keywords` but I am struggling with linking these counts back to the original name as shown in the desired output: `counts`.

Current code (I think I am slowly getting there):

```
freq_dict = {}
for p in people:
    name = p['name']
    for c in p['keywords']:
        if c not in freq_dict:
            freq_dict[name] = {c: 1}
        else: 
            if c not in freq_dict[name]:
                freq_dict[c] = 1
            else:
                freq_dict[c] +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension along with `collections.Counter` which does exactly what you want with the nested list. -

```
from collections import Counter

[{'name':i.get('name'),
  'keywords':[dict(Counter([j for j in i.get('keywords') 
                            if j in common_keywords]))]} for i in people]
```

```
[{'name': 'Bob', 'keywords': [{'dog': 2}]},
 {'name': 'Kate', 'keywords': [{'cat': 1}]},
 {'name': 'Sasha', 'keywords': [{'person': 1, 'cat': 1}]}]
```

---

1. First, with the list comprehension you want to reconstruct the original list of dicts with keys separately defined along with `i.get('key')`. This will let to work with the nested list value for keywords.
2. Iterate over the list and filter only the ones in common_keywords
3. Pass this list into collections.Counter to get your dict
4. Return it as a list with a single dict inside as you expect it to be

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Made another edit.